# If/Else condition using specific time ranges

Tags: javascript, html, date, if-statement, time

I'm trying to formulate an if/else condition with the following criteria using javaScript:

"Good Morning" if the time is between 5:45 am and 11:59:59 am
"Good Afternoon" if the time is between 12:00 pm and 05:59:59 pm
"Good Evening" if the time is between 6:00 pm and 5:44:59 am

Comment: You should add [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: What is your question, exactly? What have you tried so far? [ask]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Date` and get current hour with `getHours` function.

```js
const d = new Date(); // get current date
const hour = d.getHours(); // get current hour

if (hour < 12)
  console.log("good morning");
else if (hour < 16)
  console.log("good afternoon");
else if (hour < 24)
  console.log("good evening");
```

If you want to work with minutes too. you can use `getMinutes` function.

```js
const d = new Date(); // get current date
const hour = d.getHours(); // get current hour
const minute = d.getMinutes(); // get current minute

  if (hour < 12 && minute < 59)
    console.log("good morning and time is hour:" + hour + " minute:" + minute);
  else if (hour < 16)
    console.log("good afternoon and time is hour:" + hour + " minute:" + minute);
  else if (hour < 24)
    console.log("good evening and time is hour:" + hour + " minute:" + minute);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you convert the time to date format you can use getHours:

```
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getHours();
```

See how to work with date and time:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gethours.asp

Comment: Problem is I need to get the exact minutes and seconds as well. I know how to just get the hours.

Comment: So you use getMinutes() and getSeconds() too.